# Besides move semantics, what are some C++11 features that would increase performance of my code?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

Move semantics has tremendous performance boost. Are there other features of C++11 that are targeted towards getting better performance?

Comment: I don't think this is too broad. If we assume a baseline categorisation of new features such as the section list on [the C++11 Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), it's trivial to go through them and work out which are performance-related.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I think "getting better performance" is pretty broad. Not only does it fail to say better than *what*, but it also presupposes that somehow performance was artificially being limited prior to C++03, which I question... clever people will always have found clever ways of doing things well.

Comment: @KerrekSB: So move semantics aren't "targeted towards getting better performance", they're "targeted towards simplifying code that uses highly-performant classes".

Comment: @SteveJessop: Right. It's a language feature that makes desirable patterns easier to express and strengthens the type system.

Comment: @KerrekSB: But it's clear that in many cases moving is more efficient than copying and that is a big part of the feature. Conversely you can confidently say that range-for in and of itself is merely a syntactical enhancement.

Comment: Of course a side-effect of making components easier to use in their "high-performance mode", is that fast code is easier and cheaper to write, and one would expect that more of it gets written. For example people who didn't bother writing swaptimizations can now benefit from moves. So there's probably a proximal *and* an ultimate target :-) I actually can't decide whether or not I agree that the distinction is important, I guess it depends what the committee had in their hearts.

Comment: @lightness except 99% of `for` loops did not go to the optimization extents of `for (:)`.  And now 50%-75%+ of new `for` loops do.

Comment: @Yakk: True. So then it comes back to whether we compare languages or the code that the languages promote. Inherently there is nothing faster about range-for, but you are quite correct about the real-world practical consequences over the world's average codebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variardic `template`s and perfect forwarding let you create easy wrappers for other code that would require `2^n` manual or macro generated functions in C++03.

The same techniques allow expression `template`s to avoid duplicating any data before the final value is extracted.

The fine grained memory model of C++11 is better than many non-standard libraries: and none of them could exist without extensions prior to C++11.  `std::atomic` can outperform mutex guarded counters in a number of applications.  Simple use of `std::async` lets you write parallel algorithms within C++ standard easily.

The smart pointers are very performant, and replacing your memory management with them can give you a boost.

`unordered` associative containers, when you do not need order, are much faster than the ordered ones.

`for(auto&&a:b)` loops can easily be faster than the loop you write your self.  You can expose looping for your own containers pretty easily too.

forwarding constructors make it easy to construct your data once, instead of constructing then initializing.

initializer lists let you initialize your data like an array, without having to create that array.

`constexpr` and the `template` improvements (variardic mainly, but also `decltype`) let you move more logic to compile time, which can enable the compiler to optimize other code much better.

User defined literals let you skip the runtime cost of converting from basic types.

lambdas let you create your own control flow 'body', which turns functor and template based control flow from obtuse and difficult to easy and transparent.  Applications from easy async code, to pixel operations auto promoted to scanline operations then dispatched to the graphics engine, to visitor code for a document tree -- all are easy to use, and often implement.

Now, none of these (including `move`) let you do things you could not do before: all programming languages are equivalent, up to a constant factor.  And C++'s C pseudo-subset is powerful enough to emulate a given C++11 program's execution with a lot, lot, lot more code (barring threading, but there is nothing in C++11 that was not in some extension library somewhere).  C++11 provides many ways to do high performance things *easily*.

Comment: "for(auto&&a:b) loops can easily be faster than the loop you write your self." - how's that?

Comment: @SteveJessop: `b` and hidden `end` are computed only once, whereas hand written `for` may compute them several times, and iterator increment is the correct one too. A **bad** loop : `for (auto it = getContainer().begin(); it != getContainer().end(); it++)`.

Comment: @Jarod42: hmm. So range-based for loops can easily be faster than the obviously bad code I assume you'd write if left to yourself? ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: It's easier for an optimizer to prove that an unnamed/hidden iterator is not aliased or changed in the loop.

Comment: @MSalters: getting a bit off-topic I admit, but can you give an example? Without looking at the iterator implementation, the compiler doesn't know whether the iterator is already aliased before the container returns it (perhaps the iterator's copy ctor ensures that copies are aliased too). If it *does* look at the iterator implementation, as is the common case, then it can tell whether or not it's aliased even if it's not hidden by analysing the loop body. Or not?

Comment: I was considering register-sized iterators, where the result of `++iter` might need to be flushed back to main memory if there was any chance of other code expecting the value there. I don't think `container.begin()` can alias the return value, because that value is copied. The copy ctor can, of course (because it's then named `*this`) but this is generally inlined woth the sort of iterators that fit in registers.

Comment: @SteveJessop Stephan T. Lavavej gave a talk at GoingNative ( http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/STL11-Magic-Secrets around 49:00). One of his arguments regarding `for` and `auto` was that auto chooses the right type which prevents automatic type conversion.

Answer (score 5):

If you're sufficiently motivated to optimize your code and write your own components, I strongly suspect that there is no new feature in C++11 (move semantics included) that achieves a performance improvement that you could not have done for yourself in C++03.

If you mean performance improvements that you get "for free" without modifying your existing C++03 code at all, then aside from move semantics there are probably a bunch of small and fairly boring library tweaks. For example changing `std::list::size` to guaranteed `O(1)` will speed up some programs using the GNU libstdc++ and slow down others.

There can't be a huge number though, simply because there aren't *very* many C++11 features that change the meaning of well-formed C++03 programs.

Comment: +1 for the good point in your first paragraph. I in fact use "move semantics" in C++03 myself. :) Actually, I think you nailed this overall.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Kerrek probably deserves that +1, since what I've done is basically re-phrase "clever people find clever ways to do things well" to directly answer the question :-)

Comment: He didn't write an answer though ;)

Comment: The standard library tweaks do mean that every `std::vector<std::string>` out there is now more efficient. In theory that specific case could have been hand-optimized before, but it wasn't.

Comment: Good point: in general there may be a large benefit from the fact that vector reallocations move instead of copying to the new buffer. I was trying to give an example other than moves, now clarified in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The only other I can think of is `constexpr`, which may enable some of your expressions to be computed at compile-time where they were not before. That said, they have to be such simple expressions that they wouldn't exactly have been imbuing your C++03 program with a performance penalty.

Consequently I'm going with **no**, unless you count the addition of standard containers that are faster for certain kinds of data than pre-existing standard containers (`unordered_map`, for instance), though these were always possible in C++03 with hand-rolled or library code.